# Write a recursive method that returns the number of occurences of 'A' in the string it is passed

Tags: java, string, recursion

So I've been fiddling with this problem for the past hour. I keep getting unexpected type error. It appears to be from a confliction between charAt and s.length. Any ideas on what could fix that?

```
class lab7
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = ("BCA");
    }

    public static String recursion(String s)
    {
        if (s.length()>=0)
        {
            if(s.charAt(s.length()) = A)
            {
                count++;
            }
            s.substring(0, s.length()-1);
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be "s.charAt(s.length()-1)".  Index of string starts from zero

Comment: Unless this is a school project - there are better ways to do this. (recursion isn't particularly performance friendly). Such as replacing A with empty and just diffing the length of two strings, or using a while loop instead of recursion.

Comment: Is this Java?  You need to tag your question with the language being used.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with this code, including some significant logic errors. However, the specific error you're getting is probably here:

```
if(s.charAt(s.length()) = A)
```

First, note that you're using = instead of ==, which does an assignment rather than a comparison. Also note that A should be in single quotes to be a character literal. Right now, Java thinks A is the name of a variable, which isn't defined. Finally, note that strings are zero-indexed, so looking up the character at position s.length() will give you a bounds error.

I hope this helps you get started! As a hint, although your function is named "recursion," does it actually use recursion?

Comment: Downvoter- can you please explain what's wrong with this answer so that I can improve it?

Answer (score 1):

Following code uses *String* class. For performance critical applications you might want to use *StringBuffer* / *StringBuilder* class accordingly.

```
class StringCounter
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        int count = returnCount("ABCDABCDABCD", 0);
        System.out.println(count);
    }
    public static int returnCount(String s, int count)
    {
        // You may want to do some validations here.
        if(s.length()==0)
        {
            return count;
        }
        if(s.charAt(0)=='A')
        {
            return returnCount(s.substring(1), count+1);            
        }
        else
        {
            return returnCount(s.substring(1), count);
        }
    }
}
```

The code simply slices the *String* parameter one character at a time and checks for the required character. Further on every *invoke* it will update the count and *String* parameter.

> Any ideas on what could fix that?

1. Your function is not *recursive*. *Recursive* functions *call* themselves with manipulated/updated parameters.
2. As a thumb rule in recursive functions, always think in terms of *manipulating* function parameters.
3. Always have a *base case* that will terminate recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this snippet:

```
static int countA(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.length() == 0) {  /* nothing or "" contains 0 A's */
        return 0;
    }
    return (str.charAt(0) == 'A' ? 1 : 0 )   /* 0 or 1 A's in first character */
                + countA(str.substring(1));  /* plus no. of A's in the rest */
}
```

And you call the function like this:

```
int a = countA("ABAABA");  /* a is 4 */
```

I realize now that this question was school related, but at least this snippet works as an exercise in understanding recursion.